# Delay in props update in a child component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my parent component, I have a button that takes the object of the selected item and renders in input fields in a child component.

The parent component renders,

```
<h4 className="table-title">Status</h4>
<div className="table-box">
    {
        props.table_data.map((item, idx) => {
            if (item.profiledata) {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <h4 className="profile-title">
                            <Button className="release-option-button" onClick={() => this.handleOpen('remove-release-profile', item)}>Remove Profile</Button>
                        </h4>
                        <Table columnWidths={[140, 220, 260, 140, 310]} numRows={item.profiledata.length}>
                                ...
                        </Table>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        })
    }
</div>
```

Whenever I click the button `release-option-button`, I `setState` the currRelease to `item`.

Then I render,

```
<EditDialog open={isOpen.EDIT_RELEASE} closeDialog={handleClose} selected_item={currRelease} />
```

and pass `currRelease` as `props.selected_item`.

And in my child component,

```
const init_fields = {
    release: props.selected_item.release,
    manager: props.selected_item.manager,
    start_date: props.selected_item.start,
    end_date: props.selected_item.end,
    profiles: props.selected_item.profiledata,
}

const EditDialog = (props) => {
    // State Hooks
    const [fields, setFields] = useState(init_fields)
    ...
```

and render these values in input fields

```
<h5>Version</h5>
<p>
    <input
        value={fields.release}
        className="input-field"
        type="text"
    />
</p>
```

However, whenever I select an item, it renders the fields of the previously selected item, instead of the current one. It seems like there is a delay in updating props.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're generating the local state for EditDialog from passed in props. With `useState`, the argument you pass is only the initial value for the state. If you want to update state based on props changing, you can use `useEffect` which can respond to prop changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
   setFields({
      release: props.selected_item.release,
      manager: props.selected_item.manager,
      start_date: props.selected_item.start,
      end_date: props.selected_item.end,
      profiles: props.selected_item.profiledata,
   });
}, [props.selected_item])
```

However, you might want to reconsider using state to store props. It's a React anti-pattern and can lead to discrepancies like this.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. This works. But I don't get the last part `you might want to reconsider using the state to store props`. Why is this an antipattern? Will it still be an antipattern even if I change the code to your answer?

Comment: You generally only want to have one source of truth for a value. In your case, is it state or is it the props? What are you using the variable 'fields' for? Perhaps you could make that object only when you need it. If it's a prop for another component, consider making the object within your render based on the props

Comment: Good article on the downfall of storing props in state: https://blog.bitsrc.io/managing-derived-state-from-props-in-react-f26b5b15069

Comment: Thanks. In my case, the source of truth is the state that I store in my redux-store. In my modal, I use the actions to update those fields using API calls. These calls will make changes to the store. I'm using props in my children components (dialogs) to show the current value or the fields of the selected object.

Comment: You'll want to rely on props here for sure. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it solved the problem